# Failure connecting MySQL server with C# ( Visual Studio )

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

to keep things short and clear:

I am trying to connect my windows form application to a mySQL server.
I've followed every instructions available on the net, but without succes.

I've followed all the steps from this article with no succes:
http://net-informations.com/q/faq/mysql.html

It won't connect whatever I try.

I have installed:
- mysql connector

and I've also added the mysql.data reference at the top.

The weird thing is, connecting to a local sql server is not a problem.
It will connect without any failures.

Here is my code that IS WORKING ( local SQL):

```html
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace csharp_mysql
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try {    
            
              
                MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=plopPlop1234;");
                myConn.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from users.users where username='" +textBox1.Text+ "' and password='" +textBox2.Text+ "'", myConn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
                int count = 0;


                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    count += 1;
                }



                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
                    
                    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                    f2.Show();
               
                this.Hide();
                }


                else if(count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("duplicate username and password");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("username or password not found");
                }

                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no connection to be made);
            }

        }
```

As soon as I change the credentials to another real mysql server ( my own hosting ),  it will stop connecting.

What is the problem here and what am I missing here?

Comment: What does the failing connection string look like? (with username/password obscured of course).

Comment: If I change the credentials to that of my own mysql server with the same set-up of code, I get the following messagebox: " There is no connection to be made " a.k.a my exception message. 

 PS: I've double checked my credentials and tested it on another PHP project it connects without a problem.

Comment: Does `localhost` still make sense for your real MySql server?

Comment: @Azzazzell: "There is no connection to be made" is your own custom error message, which doesn't provide very much information.  What is the *actual* error message in the exception?

Comment: my bad... the actual error is : "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."}.

Comment: Pim, the code I embedded is the code that IS working ( local SQL ). I showed it as an example. but as soon as I change my mysql connection string to my actual mysql ( my own hosting ), I get the error I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.", check if your hosting allow remote connections.